# replacing css files from content page

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, css, vb.net

Master page (C.masterpage) has a parent master page (P.masterpage)  which has all 10 css files included in head. These css files are being applied in all site.

We are creating some new pages in which we want different styles so requirement is to replace (stop previous sheets, or remove if possible) two style sheets and add new style sheets and make them working instead of old.

In P.Masterpage all css files are in head tag which is with runtat server. I also have content place holder in p.masterpage but these css files are out of it and in p.masterpage content place holder is just an empty tag. Please guide me how do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Why not just declare the base set of stylesheets in a new parent master page, derive your current master page from that, adding in the two old style sheets so no changes will need to be made to your existing pages. Then define a new child master age with the other two (new) stylesheets and inherit from that master for the new pages?

Saves hacking about on a page-by-page basis...

So current master (l1) becomes a child of a new master page (containing only the core/common stuff) and a new master also inherits from the new master page but defines its own two separate stylesheets...

Comment: thanks. But how I will stop 2 previous styles sheets not being applied on my pages ?

Comment: By only inheriting from the relevant level2 master page that contains the two *new* stylesheets. The old ones will only be referenced by the other level2 master page. If you dont want any of the level2 master page stuff, then just inherit from the top level master page.

Comment: LDJ I got your point, this way will sure apply 2 new style sheets but will not remove/ stop working the previous style sheets which is requried as well.